# Why is Xcode's debugger jumping around this way with Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, swift

I debugged the following code with `F6` in `Xcode 6`, and the sequence of execution is very interesting.

Here is the code - 7 lines, a breakpoint is set on line 1:

```
    let request = AWSDynamoDBPutItemInput()
    request.tableName = "blah"

    let card = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    card.S = "1234"
    let email = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    email.S = "notset"

    request.item = ["card_number" : card, "email" : email]
```

When I F6'd through the code, it showed the following sequence (the numbers are line numbers):

```
1,2,4,2,3,4,6,4,5,6,7,6,7
```

Why is this? Is this something with Xcode or the language? Those classes are defined in Amazon's AWS SDK, not sure whether that matters, they are accessed through swift-objective-c bridging, could this be related to the bridging.

By the way, the net result of the execution is correct.

Comment: That's pretty much normal -- you see similar with regular Objective-C, and I'd expect the effect to be a hair worse with Swift.

Comment: It's really not that unusual in any environment.  Especially with loops you'll see a jump to the bottom when starting up and/or to the top when ending.  And the logic behind ARC adds more strangeness.

Comment: @peter did you find a solution. I feel like Im going crazy here trying to code while my screen goes crazy.

Comment: @Peter Pei Guo nice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a reply to my bug report from `Apple`, and sounds like it was a bug and got fixed in a beta version of `XCode`. If you are seeking for a fix, please try the beta:

> We believe this issue has been addressed in the latest Xcode 6.3 beta, including iOS 8.3 SDK with Swift 1.2.
>
> Please test with this release.  If you still have issues, please include any relevant logs or information that could help us investigate.
>
> This is a pre-release version of the complete Xcode developer toolset for Mac, iPhone, iPad, and Apple Watch. This release requires OS X Yosemite.
>
> Xcode 6.3 - Build 6D520o
> https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: Thanks, sadly I can't use XCode 6.3 with my current project until its out of beta. However, I will check it out.

Comment: problem is still there with osx yosemite , xcode 6.3(stable) and iOS 8.4.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're observing is the effect of the compiler optimizations. It rewrites your code at compile time. For this reason it's normal to disable optimization (`-Onone`) on debug builds, but enable it (`-Ofast` or `-Os`) on release builds.

Answer (score 0):

You should open your project and targets configuration page, under the build settings tab, locating the "Apple LLVM 6.1- code generation" tag, change the optimization level for debug to be "None [-O0]", clean your project and you are done!